# Best way to set up Google Analytics for same app, multiple platforms

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, analytics

What's the best way to set up Google Analytics to track one app on multiple platforms (e.g. Android, iOS).

The app is very similar on all the platforms, so we'd like to view activity in aggregate, but also have the ability to cut by key values such at platform, user state (signed in, signed out etc)

Also, what's the best way to track a unique instance of the app (as a user)? Is there some way to create a unique ID on install that stays in all tracking calls for the lifetime of the install?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I did is make a list of what I want to track and name them the same thing in both apps. The code in the app will be different from android to iOS. 
But for the analytics part just use one project in the google dev console. Then add both app to the project like the docs say. you will have to follow the steps in the google documentation. But just keep it in the same project and then both devices types will be in the same project and you won't have to juggle two projects at the same time. 
It works great doing it like that